# Why the font-size and div will merge together when I drag and drop the items?

Tags: javascript, html, css

recently I am trying to make a drag and drop game.

The game is almost finished. However, when I try to drop the items to "Drop Items Here", the items' style will changed as "Drop Items Here", like below:

[image]

Also if I drop the items together, they will merge, like below:

[image]

As I am a beginner so the code may look very weird. Is there any way to avoid merging the items and style together after drop? Thank you very much.

```js
function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
function drag(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
}
function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  if (data == "1"|"2"|3|4){
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
}
```

```css
.Drag{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
.lists {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;

}
.lists .list{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex: 1;        
    margin: 0 15px;
}
.lists .list .item {
    background-color: #0099ff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 3px solid #0085de;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-align: left;
    margin:4px 0px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.DropHere{
  text-align: center;
  color:#d9d9d9;
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "Drag">
    <div class = "lists">       
        <div class = "list">
            <div>Drag and drop</div>            
                <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" 
                     style="border-style: dashed; border-color:grey; border-radius: 18px; height: 600px;">
                    <p class = "DropHere">Drop items here</p>
                </div>              
            </div>
        <div class = "list">
            <div class = "item" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id = "1">This is a</div>
            <div class = "item" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id = "2">This is b</div>
            <div class = "item" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">This is c</div>  
            <div class = "item" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">This is d</div>  
            <div class = "item" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id = "3">This is f</div> 
            <div class = "item" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id = "4">This is g</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like `event.target.appendChild(...)` is the issue. Try specifying the actual div instead of the target. Need to add an ID to the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a P page in the Drop Items Here box. Pull this P tag out and set with CSS. Check this code.

```js
function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
function drag(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
}
function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  if (data == "1"|"2"|3|4){
  event.target.closest(".drag-box-output").appendChild(document.getElementById(data));}
}
```

```css
.Drag{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.lists{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;

}

.lists .list{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex: 1;
    
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.lists .list .item {
    background-color: #0099ff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 3px solid #0085de;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-align: left;
    margin:4px 0px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.DropHere{
  text-align: center;
  color:#d9d9d9;
  font-size: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
/* add this CSS*/
.drag-box{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.drag-box-output{
padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "Drag">
        <div class = "lists">       
            <div class = "list">
                <div>Drag and drop</div>   
                <div class="drag-box">
                <div class="drag-box-output" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style = "border-style: dashed; border-color:grey; border-radius: 18px; height: 600px;"></div><p class = "DropHere">Drop items here</p></div>
            </div>
        <div class = "list">
            <div class = "item" draggable = "true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id = "1">This is a</div>
            <div class = "item" draggable = "true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id = "2">This is b</div>
            <div class = "item" draggable = "true" ondragstart="drag(event)">This is c</div>    
            <div class = "item" draggable = "true" ondragstart="drag(event)">This is d</div>    
            <div class = "item" draggable = "true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id = "3">This is f</div>   
            <div class = "item" draggable = "true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id = "4">This is g</div>   

        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, when I try to put two items together, two items still merger together.